# Power filter value based on the filter selection

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

I have different shipment data single sheet like  below screen shot for reference

```
Trucksp Truckquty    Filter  Seasp  Seaquty   Filter  STOsp  STOquty   Filter 
 45       66         TRUCK   55       67      SEA      34      45      STO
 55       76         TRUCK   55       97      SEA      44      55      STO

 45       66         TRUCK   25       27      SEA      22      88      STO
```

if i select truck filter i want show only trucksp and truckquty divide value . value should be show based on the filter selection . any idea .please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
Measure= divide(max(tbl[trucksp]), max(tbl[truckquty))
```

Comment: i have slicer following values  TRUCK   ,SEA,STO . but when i choose truck slicer value should be truck but this is single sheet i am getting whole calculation